# Firehose pattern - real-time streaming in kafka

Tags: events, design-patterns, apache-kafka

In a book called Typescript microservices, I found a sentence containing weirdly named pattern, called "Event Firehose". I can't find any definition of this pattern in google. I quoted a sentence below.

> When you want to use real-time streaming, use the Event Firehose pattern, which has KAFKA as one of its key components.

Comment: It should probably be **Firehose**

Comment: Except Kafka isn't exactly a firehose pattern. You need to explicitly subscribe to a namespace/topic. Compare this to listening to the public Twitter feed, which is one API endpoint, but hashtags need to be filtered out in a separate process